# How to fix no-unsafe-call for Set in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
private static bar()
{
    const s = new Set();
    foo(s);
}
    
private static foo(
s: unknown   )   
{
    s.add("123"); 
}
```

I got `Unsafe call of any typed value` in the add() function call because I have eslint. What should I do to fix this? I think I need a type for s, but I am not sure which type I should use.

Comment: Did you check the [no-unsafe-call](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-call.md) rule first for information? The linter is complaining because the `s` parameter is `unknown`, and thus `add` is being invoked on an unresolved type. The full context of your snippet isn't apparent, but it seems like you'd want to adjust the signature to something like: `private static foo<T>(s: Set<T>) { ... }`

Comment: ah! I am 2 days new to typescript. Thanks, I think this will solve the issue.